# Export JTable into Excel file

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf, hssf

here I am trying to export JTable into excel file...I didn't get any error on console...but on excel sheet I got only column names...my aim is want to show database table in this JTable square, and below this there is Export button,so after clicking this button excel file should be created for above displaying JTable.

so cant recognized actual error

```
    JButton btnExport = new JButton("Export");
    btnExport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            try 
            {
                String query="Select * from client";
                PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
                HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
                rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Client_Vendor code");
                rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Client_Name");
                rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Purchaser_Name");
                rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("User_Name");
                rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Sales_Engg");

                int index=1;
                while(rs.next())
                    {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getInt(1));
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
                    row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));
                    row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
                    row.createCell(4).setCellValue(rs.getString(5));
                    index++;

                    }  

                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("e:/CLIENTDATA/client.xlsx");
                    wb.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.close();
                    System.out.println("Data is saved in excel file.");
                 }
                catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You are basically overwriting the file on each iteration of the `while (rs.next())` loop, instead, write it after the loop as completed

Comment: @MadProgrammer ohhh..yes thank you so much..

Comment: Dbutils is reading to the end of the resultset. Don't use it, build the TableModel as you read the resultset

Comment: can you just elaborate with code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is right here...

```
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

`DBUtils` is reading to the end of the `ResultSet`, meaning when you call `rs.next()`, it returns `false`, because there is no more data

You have two chocies...

## You Could...

Call [`ResultSet#beforeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst--), but this is not supported by all database and there may be a performance hit

## You Could...

Stop using `DBUtils` and build the `TableModel` manually.  Start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

```
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
    String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(col + 1);
    model.addColumn(columnName);
    rowhead.createCell(col).setCellValue(columnName);
}

int index = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector tableRow = new Vector(columnCount);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index);
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
        Object value = rs.getObject(col + 1);
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            row.createCell(col).setCellValue((int) value);
            tableRow.add((int) value);
        } else {
            row.createCell(col).setCellValue(value.toString());
            tableRow.add(value.toString());
        }
    }
    model.addRow(tableRow);
}

try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("e:/CLIENTDATA/client.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```

I'd also recommend having a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: I tried this code as it is, but i got only last row in excel file..but my aim is want to show database table in  this JTable square, and below this there is Export button,so after clicking this button excel file should be created for above displaying JTable.

Comment: So now you're saying the export process is different from the loading of the table!?

Comment: @MadProgrammer..thank you for the code...problem resolved